# How To Search authorized_keys For Public Key And Remove It

Tags: linux, bash

Hello I am looking for assistance searching `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` for a given public key (call it $pub_key) and removing it. Want to do this in bash script.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would `grep -v $pub_key /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /tmp/authorized_keys.new` work?  You can compared to two files to verify the work.  Given the long strings of random characters that comprise the keys, it's probably sufficient to do this using a substring of $pub_key.

Comment: Actually, that just cleared out the entire file, it didn't just remove the passed in `$pub_key`

Comment: I think I need to use sed, but can't figure out the syntax, here is what I have thus far: `sed -i '/$pub_key/ d' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Seriously, the grep didn't work?  Try a substring.  Something like "grep -v CqcQ9rbUrPBczdoHBAe72Z /root/.ssh/authorized_keys".  There's so much entropy in these keys that any reasonably sized substring won't be repeated in any other key.  You don't need to need the whole 500+ character key.  The syntax on the sed is correct, though I would be nervous about using the "-i" option; make backups if you use it.

Answer (score 2):

Never forget the power of perl oneliners!

```
$pub_key="AAAABCD"; perl -i "/$pub_key/ or print" /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

That will perform an in-place edit and remove the offending key.

Or, perhaps you have a really really long authorized_keys file and you want to process it in parallel with [gnu parallel](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gnu%20parallel&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fs%2Fparallel%2F&ei=-VRpTprpO8WqsQKa-73lDQ&usg=AFQjCNG_MUbgWB6LzkDGbBu29_iUzm5w8g&cad=rja)?

```
pub_key="AAAABCD"; parallel -k "echo {} | grep -v $pub_key" </root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

the possibilities are endless.

update: fixed typo that Ole pointed out.  Thanks Ole!

Comment: Remove the first $ to set the variable. Apart from that you should consider using --pipe if your authorized_keys is of the size where it will benefit from parallel processing.

Comment: Ole is there a way to do 'edit in place' with parallel as above?

Answer (score 2):

> I think I need to use sed, but can't figure out the syntax, here is
>   what I have thus far:
>
> ```
> sed -i '/$pub_key/ d' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```

Remove the space before `d`, it will work as you expect:

```
sed -i '/$pub_key/d' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: My keys have a half-dozen slash characters in them that would need to be escaped.  I would use `'\|$pub_key|d'` to get sed to use `|` as an alternate delimiter rather than adding backslashes to $pub_key

Comment: Hmm.  If you insist on using $pub_key for the whole key, do something this: "$substring = `echo $pub_key | cut -c30-60` ; mv authorized_keys authorized_keys.bak ; grep -v $substring authorized_keys.bak > authorized_keys".  grep doesn't care about the delimiters.  When it didn't work before, you probably expressed $pub_key as the whole thing, but there are spaces in there.  In that case, you should have mentioned the error, and I would have suggested enclosing $pub_key in quotes.